# Tinkerpop/Gremlin Breadth first traversal

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, graph-traversal

I'm trying to traverse a graph to trace the lineage of a specific node. I would like my query to yield the antecedents to that node in a breadth first pattern. Note, each node can have multiple parents. The Graph can be many layers deep and I'd like to see the results of all levels for a given node. I'm trying to follow along [this](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Depth-First-vs.-Breadth-First) recipe, but run into the exception No such property: gather. I'm trying this on the gremlin console version 3.3

Answer (score 3):

Use a `barrier()` step ([Apache TinkerPop 3.3 docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/reference/#barrier-step)). For example:

```
gremlin> g.V().sideEffect{println "first: ${it}"}.barrier().sideEffect{println "second: ${it}"}.iterate()
first: v[1]
first: v[2]
first: v[3]
first: v[4]
first: v[5]
first: v[6]
second: v[1]
second: v[2]
second: v[3]
second: v[4]
second: v[5]
second: v[6]
```

Stephen gives another good description of BFS in this [gremlin-users post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/tc8zsoEWb5k/9X9LW-7bCgAJ).

> First, let's assume a Gremlin language without optimization - doing:
>
> `g.V().out().out()`
>
> will result in a depth first search. You can force BFS with barrier():
>
> `g.V().out().barrier().out()`
>
> which basically will force the step prior to drain before moving on to the next step.